# Sumar el resultado anterior a otra suma

Tags: c

**Sumar el resultado anterior a otra suma**

Hola, necesito hacer lo siguiente: Ingresar un número `i` y un numero `j`, `i`
siendo el inicio, `j` siendo el final y cada iteración debe sustituir la suma
del siguiente número, es decir: `i = 1 j = 5`. Asi:

```
1 + 2 = 3, 2 + 3 = 5, 3 + 5 = 8, 4 + 8 = 12, 5 + 12 = 17
```

Otro ejemplo sería:

```
 i = 10 j = 13
 10 + 11 = 21, 11 + 21 = 32, 12 + 32 = 44, 13 + 44 = 57
```

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
e = a + b; 
for (c = a; c <= b; ++c){
     for (d = b; d<=e; ++d);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n",c,d,e);             
}
```

Entiendo que "e" también tiene que meterse en un for, sin embargo no
llego a comprender como hacerlo. ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Hola una pregunta de tu ejemplo: `1 + 2 = 3, 2 + 3 = 5, 3 + 5 = 8, 4 + 8 = 12, 5 + 12 = 17`. Si 3 + 5 es 8 por que luego sigue 4 +8. No debería ser 5 + 8 = 13 ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sumar el resultado anterior a otra suma**

Hola, siguiendo un poco la lógica de su explicación entiendo que el código debe ir sumando a pares, de manera que cada número es igual a la suma de sus dos anteriores, de manera que:

```
1+2= 3, 2+3= 5, 3+5=8 ...
```

Ha este patrón se que se le conoce como la **sucesión de Fibonacci**:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55…
```

Si es así, la lógica que quieres lograr con tu código en C esto te puede ayudar:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    printf("Ingrese un numero entero para i:");
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Ingrese un numero entero para j:");
    int j;
    scanf("%d",&j);
    
    printf("Ingrese un entero para determinar el numero de ejecucion del bucle: ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int iteraciones= 0; /*Numero de veces a ejecutar la funcion*/

    while(iteraciones < n){
        iteraciones++;
        int resultado= i + j;

        printf(" %i) %i + %i = %i \n",iteraciones,i,j,resultado);

        i= j;
        j= resultado;
    }

    getch(); /* Pausa */

    return 0;
}
```

**Explicación del código**

Creamos las variables `i` y `j` que recibirán los enteros a sumar. Para realizar la suma una determinada cantidad de veces y la reasignación de variables uso un bucle `while`. Este bucle será controlado por una variable que recibirá un entero que le dirá cuantas veces ejecutar el bucle. Pues este patrón de suma es infinito. Al final el resultado será impreso en consola.